# Need regualar expression pattern that replaces a specific value in filepath

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file path like :

```
var path="/JBL/Deliverable/Rollover/1296170/2019-Aug-29/
731222/financing Consulting, LLC-Rollover Notice / Notice of Conversion-August -2019.pdf"
```

I need to get the file name from path.And Im using below regex and its working as expected

```
path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

So it would give the data after last slash(/) that ends with. extension

```
output: Notice of Conversion-August -2019.pdf
```

But now I have a requirement that if the filename start with either Notice of Conversion (or) Workers Compensation then I need that data from previous slash(/) i.e.,

```
 financing Consulting, LLC-Rollover Notice / Notice of Conversion-August -2019.pdf
```

Similarly if path is

```
/JBL/Deliverable/Rollover/1296170/2019-Aug-29/
731222/financing Consulting, LLC-General Liability / Workers Compensation-Quarterly-August -2019.pdf
```

then it should give

```
financing Consulting, LLC-General Liability / Workers Compensation-Quarterly-August -2019.pdf
```

For any other file names it should work as it is.
Can someone please help with this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternation `|`

```
(?:\/[^/]+\/\s*Notice of Conversion.*?|\/[^/]+)$
```

[image]

```js
let paths = ["/JBL/Deliverable/Rollover/1296170/2019-Aug-29/731222/financing Consulting, LLC-Rollover Notice / Notice of Conversion-August -2019.pdf","/JBL/Deliverable/Rollover/1296170/2019-Aug-29/731222/financing Consulting, LLC-Rollover Notice / xyz-August -2019.pdf"]

paths.forEach(path=>{
  let fileName = path.match(/(?:\/[^/]+\/\s*Notice of Conversion.*?|\/[^/]+)$/gi)[0].substring(1,).trim()
  console.log(fileName)  
})
```

Comment: Hi @Code Maniac.It is working fine for Notice of Conversion.but it should also work if it starts with "Workers Compensation".How can we include this as well

Comment: @user7350714 you can use alternation there as well, i.e `(?:\/[^/]+\/\s*(?:Workers Compensation|Notice of Conversion).*?...`

Comment: Can we achieve the same functionality using replace function without using forEach..?We have some limitation in our tool

Comment: @user7350714 yes you can, add `^.*` at start of pattern and add the above pattern in capturing group and replace with `$1`, i.e. `string.replace(/^.*/(?:\/[^/]+\/\s*(?:Workers Compensation|Notice of Conversion)...))/gi, "$1")`